# Copado User Story showing Potential Conflict with Old User Story Which is Already Deployed

Tags: conflict, git-merge-conflict, user-stories

My team is trying to deploy changes (flow metadata) from DEV to UAT and it is showing "Potential Conflict" with another user story which is already being deployed into Production almost 5 months back and also back-promoted. My understanding is that once the story is deployed successfully, the feature branch will be merged with the main branch and after a successful merge, that features branch will never be used to identify any potential conflict for any future user stories. Is my understanding wrong?